# Backup broken PostgreSQL 8.4 without pg_dump

Tags: debian, backup, postgresql, debian-squeeze, init.d

So. I have [a problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/419884/how-to-restart-postgresql-8-4-on-debian-squeeze). PostgreSQL 8.4 won't start or restart without any output given.

But it worked for 3 monthes until hosting provider doesn't rebooted server. Now it is completly broken. It wan't start and doesn't give any output or log.

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "postgres" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Now I want to backup (or just start pgsql socket) my database to reinstall postgesql. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo. Here is the solution.

The problem was my postgresql (for some reason :o) didn't have any clusters creates.

So I created one:

```
pg_createcluster 8.4 main
```

Now let's find something silimar to old data folder: `find / -name 'PG_VERSION'`

Here it is – `/usr/local/pgsql/data/`. Now edit `postgresql.conf` in your cluster folder.

You have to replace `data_directory` varaible value with old folder.

Now you can restart your server. Everything will work fine.